# Why do most games save the players team as a short int in the player class and not as a pointer to a team object?

Tags: software-engineering

Why do most games save the players team as a `short int` in the player class and not as a pointer to a team object. As far as I know both methods have their advantages.

**Short method:**

- Saving it as a short is smaller;
- Syncing players will be faster because of the first point.
- Syncing players will be easier because the memory location can be different on another PC.

**Pointer method:**

- You could for example save a team name. That way you don’t need to
  look it up every time you need it;
- It’s more OOP.

I saw a lot of engines saving the team as a `short int`. What are the reasons that they save the players team as a short and not as a pointer?

Comment: thats a weirdly localized question

Comment: I think it's actually a *good* question, depending how you interpret it.  It's current wording invites discussion, but read it as "which should should I use?" and it's good and useful; certainly not too localized as it's a crucial point for any client/server architecture.

Comment: How do you know what **most** games do?

Comment: @Trevor Powell There are a lot of open source engines and there is always the reverse engineer option.

Comment: @mh01 I'm not creating a game, why do you that this is a “what should I use” question?

Comment: @GameDev-er why?

Comment: The assumption is that if you're asking a question on this site, it's in relation to something you're doing. If that's not the case then maybe it does fall into the "invites discussion" category & should be closed. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Define "saving", in the context of this question.  Are you referring specifically to "save games"?  Or are you talking about representation in memory?  Or in network data packets?  Or something else?

Comment: @mh01 I'm asking this because I had a discussion about it. I would like to know why the pointer method is barley used. I see for both parts the logic behind it. But I wanted to know what can go wrong with each of these. So it’s more learning ;).

Comment: @Trevor Powell in the player class. So that will be in memory.

Comment: @Laurence - In that case it's necessary to refer you to the site's FAQ: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask - "*You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page*."  Voting to close.

Comment: it assumes that most games do that, and only applies to multi-player games where the player has a team. its just a very specific weird thing to ask.

Comment: @mh01 ahh, now I understand the meaning of your question. I thought I mentioned that i'm only creating the design. But I didn't.

Comment: @GameDev-er This is also relevant for local games. Besides that, there are a lot of game types that can use this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common reason is, there simply is no Team object, a int or enum will suffice.

But your assertions are slightly flawed. So let my iterate on them and finally tell you why an int is also a good idea even with a Team object.

First, yes a short *may* be smaller than a pointer. True on a PC, but it is nowhere guaranteed. (Yes, this is sort of academic.) I doubt that saving or sending 16 bits or 64 bits makes such a difference really and you do not want to send the pointer's address anyway. If you have an IP network to sync over, the network's structure will certainly determine how fast you can sync the player state.

As noted above, you never want to send the address of a pointer over a network or save into a file. You need a way to represent this information in a stable way, thus you give each team and id (int) and store/send this. The receiving/reading end then looks up the team from that id.

At this point you can put a pointer to the Team into the Player object. It has no or little effect to storing or syncing objects.

There **may** be a reason why you still don't want to refer to other game objects by pointer, *but this depends on your engine design*. For example you may have some delayed message mechanic. So you send a message to the object (maybe even to itself) to be delivered later, but in the meantime the object is deleted. By using a unique int it is possible to safely handle the message, the lookup fails and the message can be silently ignored. If it was a hardcoded pointer it would have crashed. You see this type of safety or weak references can often be found in code. (Google "Handle" for more info.)

And on a closing note, *"It's more OOP"*. We are software engineers and not software zealots, thus we don't adhere to dogma. Any design discussion must based on real principles that have a well defined gain. Any person that says this is the right way to do it should get their brains unwashed. It don't want to say that OOP is bad, no it is great, but "this is the right way to do OOP" is a non starter.

Comment: "*We are software engineers and not software zealots, thus we don't adhere to dogma.*" For the love of God, ***this!*** If we had signatures in our posts, that would now be mine.

Answer (score 2):

Are we talking about short int? If so, the main advantage is data serialization. Int is a POD (plain old data). It's way easier to save and load an ID (short int in this case) rather than recreating the OOP pointer to class.

Btw : Speed is negligible in this case

Comment: This is about a short int indeed.

Comment: The "OOP pointer" could very well be `void****` (I've seen this before).  How OOP is that.